# Radio Button Size

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which I have number of radio buttons. But the size of the radio button is very big. How can I reduce the size of these radio buttons? Thanks in advance.

Comment: give fixed size of radio button

Comment: i tried give width and height but it is not working... same in wrap_content too

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom radio buttons using your own images. This may help: [Is it possible to change the radio button icon in an android radio button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer...https://stackoverflow.com/a/5547552/1320245
Basically, you can set the size in the XML for the layout.