# Only one radio button selected at a time

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have two radio button in a radio group. I also have 2 androd:button checkbox- for when the radio button is deselected and checkbox_v for when he user selects the checkbox. I also implemnted that a method `onRadioButtonClick` in order to make sure that only one radio button had drawable:checkbox and the other has checkbox_v . How can I implemnt onRadioClick to do this? any idea?

```
public void onRadioButtonClick(View v)
{
    RadioButton button = (RadioButton) v;
    boolean checkBox1Selected;
    boolean checkBox2Selected = false;

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        button.getId()+ " was chosen."+R.id.wificheckBox,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if ( button.getId() ==R.id.wificheckBox) {
        // Toggle status of checkbox selection
        checkBox1Selected = radiowifiButton.isChecked();

        // Ensure that other checkboxes are not selected
        if (checkBox2Selected) {
            radiomobileButton.setChecked(false);
            checkBox2Selected = false;
        }
        else if (button.getId() ==R.id.wifimobilecheckBox) {
            // Toggle status of checkbox selection
            checkBox2Selected = radiomobileButton.isChecked();
            // Ensure that other checkboxes are not selected
            if (checkBox1Selected) {
                radiowifiButton.setChecked(false);
                checkBox1Selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

main xml

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/wifimobilecheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/button_radio"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClick" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wificheckBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wificheckBox"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="WiFi or mobile network"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_2"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/wificheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/button_radio"

        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClick" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/wificheckBox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wificheckBox"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="WiFi "
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

Drawabe- button_radio

```
<item android:state_checked="true"android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_v"/><item android:state_checked="false"android:state_pressed="false"'android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>
```

Comment: what you tried? paste your code here

Answer (score 14):

If they are in a radiogroup, only one can be selected at a time. If you want both to be able to be selected, remove them from the radiogroup.

Comment: Incorrect. I am customizing the radio button with my own drawable drawable/checkbox and drawable/checkbox_v instead of the standard one. Currently I can select both radi buttons and the are both setting the image drawable/checkbox_v

Answer (score 4):

As the top voted answer didn't work for me as for many others. I am sharing the method that i used and its working perfectly.

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/rb_female"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_female"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:button="@drawable/selector_radio_button"
                android:text="Female" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@drawable/selector_radio_button"
                android:text="Male" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Setting the `android:checkedButton="@+id/rb_female"` worked for me in `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your onRadioButtonClick method and add OnCheckedChangeListener to your radiogroup. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html

I guess by implementing your own click handler your are overwriting some functionality of the radiogroup.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear. Would you mind to make it simpler. I tried my best to understand your requirements and these are the findings given below :(.

A radio button can have text. So you don't have to add another `TextView` in your layout. Please remove them and add a simple `android:text="blah.. blah.."` to your radiobutton.

With my understanding you have two doubts.

**How to customize RadioButtons with custom drawables??**

Checkout the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259295/how-can-i-set-the-width-of-radio-buttons-to-change-with-regards-to-screen-size).

**How to deselect the previously selected radiobutton??**

The truth is you don't have to do it manually as you are keeping those radiobuttons into a single radiogroup.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To check/uncheck radio buttons not part of a RadioGroup,
add a method in the android GUI designer under the
RadioButton Properties 'onClick' (In this example radio1_onClick).

In your activity.xml under the xml for the RadioButton

```
RadioButton 
    [blah blah blah]
    android:id="@+id/radio1"
    android:onClick="radio1_onClick"
```

In your activity_main.xml you would write the following method.

```
private void radio1_onClick(View v)
{
    CompoundButton b=(CompoundButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    b.setChecked(true); /* light the button */

    //b.setChecked(false); /* unlight the button */
}
```