# Prevent views from overflowing

Tags: android

I have a `RadioGroup` with 8 `RadioButton`s and horizontal orientation. The screen can accommodate 7 `RadioButton`s without congestion. But for the 8th `RadioButton`, only half of it is displayed. How to make it appear in the next line instead?

Comment: capture emulater image and show

Comment: can you post your xml?

Comment: set parent layout to just match parent in width, not wrap content and it should be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the custom radio button using the selector.
widthOfButton = screenWidth/NoOfRadioButton

Visit the link [How can I set the width of radio buttons to change with regards to screen size? (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259295/how-can-i-set-the-width-of-radio-buttons-to-change-with-regards-to-screen-size)

Hopefully your problem will be short out.