# Android-Dynamically change the size of radio button based on screen width and text

Tags: android, dynamic, radio-button

I have 4 radio buttons in one radio group. The problem is that the text is too long, so the text shows up on multiple lines. I want the text to show up on only one line, so is it possible for the radio button size (the image and the text) to decrease so the buttons fits on one line?

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

As you can see, the text is showing up on 2-3 lines because it's too long. I've tried to decrease the text size, which works, but then the text is too small. I want to decrease the text and the image together so the text won't look as small and it's still readable.

`android:scaleX` and `android:scaleY` made the radio buttons (the images and the text) smaller, but the radio buttons still occupied the same space and the text was still occupying 2-3 lines.

Comment: Take a look at this link.Refer the first answer. [Dynamic Radio Button Size]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259295/how-can-i-set-the-width-of-radio-buttons-to-change-with-regards-to-screen-size

Comment: Sorry this didn't help me.