# How to decrease the size of an Image on a RadioButton to a desired size in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, android-fragments, android-radiobutton

I am trying to form 3 radio buttons with Image on them. So I have used the XML attribute `android:button`. But since my image size is too big, I can't see it fit in the button.

Following is my XML code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/netbankingRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    tools:context=".activities.fragments.NetBankingFragment">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listOfBanks"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/sbi"
                android:text="SBI"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:button="@drawable/sbilogo"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>


            <RadioButton
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/axis"
                android:text="AXIS"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/citi"
                android:text="CITI"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </TableRow>




    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What I'm getting here is [image: this]. What I'm trying to get here is [image: this]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make the image small by using some other **Image editing tool** as "Paint.net"

Comment: Is that the only way??

Comment: i also have to use this way...after long searching i too had found only this way..

Comment: Tried.. Didn't work. Do you know if an ImageButton can be used as a RadioButton in Android?

Comment: we can use drawables with radio buttons as...<RadioButton
    android:button="@drawable/yourdrawable" 
    ...
/>

Answer (score 0):

You should place your drawables in an xml file for radio buttons and then simply set `android:button` to the xml file, instead of drawable. If you do so you can simply change the size using width/height attributes. For more information read this thread [How can I set the width of radio buttons to change with regards to screen size? (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259295/how-can-i-set-the-width-of-radio-buttons-to-change-with-regards-to-screen-size) and its top answer.